# Why do tuples have uses_allocator but pairs don't?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

While experimenting with the C++11 `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` as implemented in gcc 4.7.0 so far, I noticed that C++11 FDIS defines a specialization of `std::uses_allocator` for tuples (`20.4.2.8[tuple.traits]`), but not for pairs, although for all other purposes, pairs look and act just like tuples (they have specializations of `std::get`, `std::tuple_size`, etc).

On further reading, [N2554](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf), which introduced these things, defined `allocator_arg` constructors and `uses_allocator` specialization for the pairs as well (pages 23-24).

Why were they dropped for pairs? Is there another way to use them that I can't see, or is this a hint of deprecation of pairs in favor of tuples?

My test code was:

```
// myalloc is like std::allocator, but has a single-argument
// constructor that takes an int, and has NO default constructor
typedef std::vector<int, myalloc<int>> innervector_t;
typedef std::tuple<int, innervector_t> elem_t;
typedef std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<myalloc<elem_t>, myalloc<int>> Alloc;
Alloc a(1,2);
std::vector<elem_t, Alloc> v(a);
v.resize(1);                  // uses allocator #1 for elements of v
// the following line fails to compile if pair is used instead of tuple
// because it attempts to default-construct myalloc<int> for innervector_t
std::get<1>(v[0]).resize(10); // uses allocator #2 for elements of innervector_t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason is that we want to avoid having 15 constructors (like in [N3000](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n3000.pdf)) for a seemingly simple class like std::pair.

We have now instead got one "general-purpose" constructor

```
template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
pair(piecewise_construct_t,
     tuple<Args1...> first_args, tuple<Args2...> second_args);
```

where you can pass just about anything you like to the constructors of each pair member, including allocators.

Comment: I see now, 4.7.0's implementation of `scoped_allocator_adaptor` is incomplete (as of last week), and lacks the overloads of `construct()` for pairs (which use piecewise construction). It is indeed sufficient for any practical use cases I could come up with.

Comment: It‘s a bad design. It's impossible to get a trival copyable tuple now.